# What's a phrase that captures someone who appreciates and is comfortable with diversity vs someone who is more comfortable with homogeneity?

Tags: phrase-requests

What's a phrase that captures someone who appreciates and is comfortable with diversity vs someone who is more comfortable with homogeneity?

Is there a phrase that's already in use that's similar to **diversity preferrers** vs **homogeneity preferrers**?

It doesn't necessarily have to do with politics or race, just the general concept of people who are comfortable meeting different people, not necessarily xenophiles, just very adaptable and thrive in such environments, happy to play different people among each other, vs people who do not.

Examples of where I want to use the phrase:

In discussing Survivor, a reality TV show where a big group of people are in competition with each other, some people are notably more comfortable playing with and around diversity. They can play with gamebots (people who do a rigid textbook strategy), people who play emotionally or play by ear, people who go the game with strong morals or non-game goals, or people who play with a ton of fear and paranoia, etc. These people are socially fearless and comfortable with a variety of different people. There are others who easily clique up with people who are like them, sometimes this is demographic via race/age/whatever, sometimes this is people who play and think like them, eg gamebots with gamebots and morals with morals.

In discussing office politics there are people who are comfortable in offices where people are putting in a diverse amount of workload vs those who are not. Most people find themselves most comfortable in an office that fits their style, slackers with slackers and go-getters with go-getters. But there are people who are comfortable with all kinds of different people and are able to navigate around the issues and to their advantage.

In a friend group, there are some friends who rigidly enforce a certain manner of behavior, ie kind and respectful, whereas other friends like to make fun of each other, prank each other, but still get along. People who can codeswitch and operate well in groups with mixed personalities and in fact enjoy meeting people who are different would be different from people who only like to hang out with people who are their style of socialization.

Basically, it would be cool if there's a term for people who prefer diverse groups and finds it advantageous vs people who really want to be in homogenous groups.

Comment: lovers of x, x lovers

Answer (score 2):

There are existing terms with the meanings

> Tending to maintain relationships with people who are different from oneself in age, race, gender, etc.

and

> tending to maintain relationships with people similar to oneself, as characterized by age, race, gender, religion, or profession

Which seems to be what you are after. However, you may find that the words '[heterophilic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heterophilic)' and '[homophilic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homophilic#English)' while apt, are prone to being misconstrued.

Comment: Thanks this is a great answer, shame on whoever downvoted you.

Comment: Like I said, prone to being misconstrued…